# How to make div covers divs on hover?

Tags: html, css, overflow

I create div which is cotnst. heigth and it's overflowing content is hidden. But when i hover it then i want do display all content. I did some [JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/h67j73rt/) but all next divs moves down. I want to hovered div covers another divs on hover but i dont know how. Please, help.

html

```
<div class="header">
</div>
<div class="container">
    <div class="content">
        </div>
    <div class="button">
        <button>
            Button
        </button>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="space">   
</div>       
<div class="footer">
</div>
```

css

```
.header
{
    background-color: violet;
    height: 40px;
}
.container{
    background-color: orange;
    width: 400px;
}
.content{
    background-color: lightblue;
    height: 100px;
    overflow: hidden;
}
.content:hover {
    overflow: visible;
    height: auto;
}
.button{
    background-color: lightgreen;
    text-align: center;
    height: 30px;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make use of the **position** and **z-index** attributes as below -

Change the two css classes

```
.container{
    background-color: orange;
    width: 400px;
    position : relative;
    /* height same as that of content. Needed to avoid the jump effect */
    height : 100px;
}

.content:hover {
    overflow: visible;
    position : absolute;
    height : auto;
    z-index:999;
}
```

Comment: I think i mentioned that clearly to make use of those attributes in **BOLD**. We don't need to explain the meaning of these attributes i guess.  Additionally, a comment is also added in the code I posted. I thought that would help enough.

Comment: @Aman Sura: thaks for help, there is a way to div cover divs but without moving covered divs? I'll show you what i mean [here](http://jsfiddle.net/h67j73rt/1/)

Comment: @AmanSura Yes, you told them what to do, but not why. People on this site come from all skill levels so answers need to provide an explanation.

Comment: @Bejkrools - Sorry i didnt get you.

Comment: When .content div is hovered then .button div moves up. This effect is unwanted, .button div shoud stay on its position.

Answer (score 2):

You can try positioning it this way (absolute), it was respond to the position of the divs above it, but over look the position of divs below it so that they can be overlapped.

```
.container{
    position:absolute;
}
```